# Retrieve INTEGER values from excel using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My aim is to read an excel file uisng POI and print the values present in it. If the value is 5 then my output must be 5. but it is returning as 5.0. The below is the code that I have tried.

```
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    XSSFSheet xssfResultSheet = null;
    String filePath = "C:\\MyXcel.xlsx";
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    xssfResultSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int iRowCount = xssfResultSheet.getLastRowNum();

    for (int i = 1; i <= iRowCount; i++) {
        Row resultRow = xssfResultSheet.getRow(i);
        System.out.println(resultRow.getCell(0));
    }
```

My Excel has values 1,2,3 but my output is 1.0,2.0,3.0. Instead my output should also be    1,2,3

Comment: AFAIK, getCell always returns float values. Have you tried parsing to Integer and then doing Math.round() on the value?

Comment: All numeric values in Excel are (64 bit) doubles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
System.out.println(resultRow.getCell(0));
```

To:

```
System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(resultRow.getCell(0)));
```

**Explanation:**

`apache-poi` provides for [`DataFormatter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibM5W.png) class as utility to leverage the format of the content *as it appears* on the excel. You can choose custom formats too, a simple example would be (cell is reference to your `XSSFCell` object):

**Excel sheet looks like:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell));
```

The above line would print:

```
50%
$ 1,200
12/21/14
9886605446
```

Whereas your normal print would interpret it differently:

```
0.5
1200.0
21-Dec-2014
9.886605446E9
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
System.out.println((int)Math.round(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Comment: This works flawlessly when the cell value to be taken as int

Comment: Just casting the returned value to int will work.                                                   
 (int) row.getCell(<CellPostion>).getNumericCellValue()

Answer (score 1):

POI should have a cell.getRawValueAsString() method, but AFAIK that's not the case. The displayed text you see in excel is the sum of value + format. So if you want to recover it "as displayed":

- Retrieve cell value from cell object
- Retrieve cell format using associated CellStyle.
- apply format to value using DataFormatter

Comment: Apache POI does have such a method though! It's [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29)

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps:

Try parseInt, after converting the cell's value to string using toString.

```
Cell cell=row.getCell(n);
```

First, convert cell's value to String using toString()

```
String cell_value = cell.toString()
```

Use parseInt to convert the same into integer:

```
int waitTime = Integer.parseInt(cell_value);
```

Now test whether the parseInt has done it's job or not.

```
System.out.print(waitTime+1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Apache POI interprets your numerial cell values as double, in order to avoid this, try to set the cell type. Maybe this will help you:

`for (int i = 1; i <= iRowCount; i++) {
        Row resultRow = xssfResultSheet.getRow(i);
        resultRow.getCell(i).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(resultRow.getCell(0).toString()));
    }`

Comment: If you look at the [Apache POI Javadocs for setCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29), they're very explicit that this is *not* the right way to do that!

Comment: Yes, this is not the right way, but is a way;) A simple to use one. Make it work and after that make it clean ;)